# How do I update entry in Contentful?

Tags: python, content-management-system, contentful

```
def update_entry(contentful_id, car_id):
    entry = environment.entries().find(contentful_id)
    entry.fields['featuredImage'] = {
            'en-US': {
                'sys': {
                    'type': 'Link',
                    'linkType': 'Asset',
                    'id': str(car_id) + '_featured_image'
                }
            }
    }
    time.sleep(10)
    entry.save()
    print("entry updated")
```

I used this code and I couldn't make it.

I have to update a field featuredImage which is a link to the asset. An asset's link is like I created it (str(car_id) + '_featured_image').

My main plan was to retrieve an entry from Contentful using ID on Contentful, add a link to the asset field, and save it. It is not working.

Also, should I publish the entry again?

Comment: Hey, if you make any changes to an entry, you need to publish it again. The changes remain in the draft state and they are not automatically published. Assuming that your code is working, you will also need to publish the entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def update_entry(contentful_id, assedId):
    entry = environment.entries().find(contentful_id)
    fields = entry.fields()

    fields['featuredImage'] = {
                'sys': {
                'type': 'Link',
                'linkType': 'Asset',
                'id': assedId
            }
    }
    
    entry.update()
    entry.save()
    entry.publish()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Okay so this is how I updated and published the entry in Contentful